# Big O vs function type definition

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I'm trying to figure out right names (definitions) to the following items.

Let's say `algorithm 1` has a time complexity like this:

```
T1(n) = 5 * n^2 + n + 123 = O(n^2)
```

How should I name algorithm that has such complexity? Is it correct to say that algorithm has `quadratic complexity type` or `algorithm type is quadratic` or `algorithm is quadratic complexity class`?

I use word `type`, because according to this [article](http://mathonweb.com/help_ebook/html/functions_4.htm), if we have a function like:

```
T(n) = n^2
```

We say that function has quadratic type.

I think that word `class` is absolutely incorrect because complexity classes is about `NP`, `NL`, etc problems.

Now let's say we have `algorithm 2` with complexity like this:

```
T2(n) = 2 * log n + 15 = O(log n)
```

UPDATE:
So the question is: Is it correct to say that algorithms 1 and 2 have different `types or classes or something else` complexities? What is the right word?

UPDATE 2:
Let's imagine the following. You are talking with your friend Bob and said: Bob, the first algorithm has quadratic complexity and the second one has logarithmic complexity. So Bob, as you can see this algorithms have different complexities ...? What word should you use instead of ...? `Types` or `classes` or maybe something else?

The problem is that english is not my native language and for me it is almost impossible to find out right definitions, when we talk about complexities. Because all I can do is try to translate it from my language, but my language does not even have this definitions.

Comment: @kelalaka I've mentioned that complexity class it is not what I'm talking about in my question.

Comment: @kelalaka I know it. My question is *not* about it. Imagine that you have two algorithms with complexities: `O(N^2)` and `O(N)`. *Is it correct* to say that both algorithm has same complexity `type`? And imagine  another algorithms with complexities T1(n) = 5 * n = O(n) and T2(n) = 9999*n = O(n) In Big O notation they have same complexities, but in reality it is not. So what exactly `n` is? `Type` of complexity or `class` or what?

Comment: Yes, both `T1(n) = 5 * n = O(n)` and `T2(n) = 9999*n = O(n)` have linear time complexity. Asymptotically, they will run in linear time. `n` is the size of input. For example 5 integers to process.

Comment: @JagrutSharma Ok, let's say we have `T1(n) = n^2 + 5` and `T2(n) = 99 * n^2` I can say that algorithms have *same* time complexity only in terms of Big O notation, but they have *different* what? Different `type` or `class` or `what`? Because it's obvious that T2 has higher growth rate and will approach infinity faster.

Comment: @kelalaka Okay, let's imagine the following. You are talking with your friend Bob and said: Bob, the first algorithm has quadratic complexity and the second one has linear complexity. So Bob, as you can see this algorithms have different complexities ...? What word should you use instead of ...? `Types` or 'classes` or maybe something else?

Answer (score 0):

`O(n^2)` is quadratic time complexity. You can refer to [this Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities) for more detailed explanation of the various time complexities.

In simple terms, you can call an algorithm that has quadratic time complexity as: **The algorithm runs in quadratic time.**

**Some more info:**

An algorithm will have a space complexity and a time complexity.

The time complexity gives information about how long the algorithm will take to run as a function of its input.

An algorithm that has a quadratic time complexity `O(n^2)` will have its run time proportional to the square of `n`. (e.g. bubble sort)

An algorithm that has logarithmic time complexity `O(log n)` will have its run time proportional to the log of `n`.
(e.g. binary search)

Both these classes have deterministic times, so they would be in complexity class `P`.

**Illustration of running time:**

`O(n)` is a better algorithm to have than `O(n^2)`. It is possible that `O(n^2)` will perform better than an `O(n)` algorithm for up to a certain `n`. But as `n` grows larger, the `O(n^2)` will be slower than an `O(n)` algorithm.

Example:

```
T1(n) = 5 * n = O(n)
T2(n) = 9999*n = O(n)
T3(n) = n^2 = O(n^2)
```

**Case 1: n=10**

```
T1 takes 5*10 = 50 sec
T2 takes 9999*10 = 99990 sec
T3 takes 10 * 10 = 100 sec
```

T3 performs better than T2, even though it is `O(n^2)`.

**Case 2: n=100**

```
T1 takes 5*100 = 500 sec
T2 takes 9999*100 = 999900 sec
T3 takes 100 * 100 = 10000 sec
```

T3 performs better than T2, even though it is `O(n^2)`.

**Case 3: n=10000**

```
T1 takes 5*10000 = 50000 sec
T2 takes 9999*10000 = 99990000 sec
T3 takes 10000 * 10000 = 100000000 sec
```

Now, T2 performs better than T3. For all `n` > 10000, T2 will perform better than T3.

Comment: Thank you, but that is not what I exactly asked. I have updated my question, please take a look.

Comment: Yes you are correct. But unfortunately it is not about my question. Imagine some algorithms with complexities `T1(n) = 5 * n = O(n)` and `T2(n) = 9999*n = O(n)` In terms of  Big O notation they have same time complexities, but in reality it is not. So what exactly n term is? Type of complexity or class or what? And also when I get complexity in Terms of Big O, how I can call this process: classification of algorithm?

Comment: Goal of using Big O notation is to `some-word-that-I-looking-for` (i don't know the word) algorithm. For example if we have algorithm like `T(n) = N^2 + n + 1 = O(N^2)`. What I've just did? Am I classify algorithm or find it type or what?

Comment: The goal of Big O notation is to indicate `how running time of an algorithm increases with the size of input n`. In other words, how fast or slow will this algorithm run as `n` increases. An `O(n)` algorithm will be faster than an `O(n^2)` algorithm as `n` increases. What you did by assigning `O(n^2)` to an algorithm is analyze its time complexity.

Comment: No, sorry you are wrong. Please take a look at  `The Art of Computer Programming - Vol 1, section "1.2.11. Asymptotic Representations", page 107`. It's not enough space here to copy all section, but Big O it just an approximation of T(n) and it has no connection with time complexity except it helps us to write in very short form dominant term of the expression without a constant.

Comment: What exactly is wrong? Big O notation is measure time complexity. Giving a book and stating to look at a page is not an answer of what Jagrut answered incorrectly.

Comment: @Marco Big O does not measure anything. In fact in was invented in 19 century. It just a math notation to denote a set of functions: O(G(N)) is the set of all functions such that there exist positive constants C and N0 with  |T(N)| ≤ C * G(N) for all N ≥ N0. So Big O is just a math framework to legally write things like `T(n) = 12 * n^2 + n  +123 + log n = O(n^2)`. it has **no** connection with complexity. But we can use it  to make life easier if we want to compare functions (including running time complexity functions)

Comment: @Marco Saying that the goal of Big O notation is to indicate how running time of an algorithm increases with the size of input n. Is like saying that goal of microscope is to hammer nail. Yes, you 100% can do that, but is it really goal of microscope?

Comment: @NoNameQA it is used to measure complexity between algorithms. It can be used to measure complexity in Order of magnitude (hence the name). No one every said it was a good way to measure it. The idea is that e.g. 2n is completely irrelevant in large data sets compared to n^2 as an example. It's a quick, easy way to give a complexity value to algorithms that are not directly comparable and allows for easy grouping. Outside of academia, Big O is not really used, it's more to understand the concept of the cost of factors influencing an algorithm. It is in no way meant to be accurate,just ballpark

Comment: @Marco My question is not about it. Please see `update 2` in my original question. Also, you said `it is used to measure complexity between algorithms`. Basically it's used **not** to `measure`, but to **compare** complexities. Moreover, even this it not perfectly correct. In simple words Big O notation  shows function's dominant terms without a constant. And according to it we can can say **only**  for functions with different dominant terms without a constant which of them has higher growth rate. For function with same dominant term without a constant Big O shows nothing.

Comment: Updated the answer to try and explain why an `O(n)` will outperform an `O(n^2)` algorithm as `n` increases.

Comment: @JagrutSharma Please see `update 2` in my original question. I'm perfectly know what Big O is, I have a degree in computer science and I wrote a desertion about algorithm complexities. What I don't know it's english words, to map my knowledge. All I need is translation. That's it.

Comment: Measure "ascertain the size, amount, or degree of (something) by using an instrument or device marked in standard units." if both have the same value, that's the comparison value. No one said Big O was a good measurement tool. All Big O is supposed to do is give the worst case as a broad result, which is the dominant term of the expression. That's it. Stop getting hung up on the word measure. Your question has already been answered, you're just hung up on grammar. It's just it scales linearly, quadraticaly, logarithmically, etc.

Comment: @NoNameQA You could say: `So Bob, as you can see these algorithms have different time complexities.`

Comment: @JagrutSharma Finally! Thank You! that's was my question! So just to make things clear: According to your answer, in english you **haven't got any words** to describe different types of complexities. So if first algorithm has complexity O(N^2) and second O(N) it is **incorrect** to say that this algorithms have different complexity types.

Comment: @Marco Big O doesn't connect with `worst case` at all. It shows `upper bound` of the function behavior. It's very different things. Worst case is all about concrete algorithm. for example `void foo(int n) {if(n == 1) return 1; for(int i = 0; i < n; i++); return n;}` Worst case `T(N) = 1 + N` here is if `n > 0`. And upper bound of this worst case is O(N)